# How to update your 32-bit JRE, after JRE8u202

Tags: java

I need to support legacy peripherals running on 32-bit OS. Now that Java 8 32-bit is EOL with the u202, what are my options going forward? I am unable to locate any other flavors of JAVA (9,10,11) in 32-bit.

Comment: You don't really have any options, you'll be stuck on 202 indefinitely unless you can drop legacy peripheral support.

Comment: There is one option.  **Pay** for Java support from Oracle.  It may cost you less to pay for Oracle support  than to buy peripherals which have 64-bit drivers.

Comment: But here's the thing.  Eventually, your legacy hardware becomes too old to support.  Too hard.  Too expensive.  Too much work.  Too unreliable.  And if you really *must* ... then you are in a bad place.

Comment: @StephenC indeed. We're still supporting a thousand or sodevices for which the sole JVM available is a non-Sun/Oracle 1.3 JVM. We're pushing our customers to replace them with modern hardware like tablets or cellphones, but it's slow going. Security worries combined with the hardware becoming impossible for them to maintain is getting them to see the need to modernise, but it's taking years already and will be years more until we can say goodbye to that codebase.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Unfortunately, replacing the legacy hardware is a monumental task, client is not prepared to pay for yet. I checked Oracle support for JRE11 32-bit downloads, but no joy. After reading Spephen's post, I opened a trouble ticket with them.